# Cassandra cluster unstable but nodetool shows all nodes are healthy (UN)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-4.0

My Cassandra cluster built on EC2 (5x node, r6i instance type)
Sometimes some node on the cluster is unstable and will increase query latency
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFiSB.png)

And during the latency high time the connection from jmx_exporter seems like unstable (green one)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pPXK.png)
The node is not able to write but able to read

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfiCo.png)
But the disk is not full

```
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root         29G  7.7G   22G  27% /
devtmpfs          62G     0   62G   0% /dev
tmpfs             62G     0   62G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             13G  960K   13G   1% /run
tmpfs            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             62G     0   62G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0        25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/6563
/dev/nvme0n1p15  105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme1n1     2.0T  170G  1.8T   9% /srv
```

And nodetool status are healthy (host id and address masked

```
# nodetool status
Datacenter: ap-southeast-1
==========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID  Rack
UN  ---  112.17 GiB  256     51.8%             ---  ap-southeast-1b
UN  ---  124.31 GiB  256     65.1%             ---  ap-southeast-1a
UN  ---  128.17 GiB  256     69.0%             ---  ap-southeast-1b
UN  ---  125.68 GiB  256     62.0%             ---  ap-southeast-1a
UN  ---  94.08 GiB   256     52.1%             ---  ap-southeast-1b
```

I'm using Cassandra 4.1.2

```
---@---:~$ nodetool describecluster
Cluster Information:
        Name: ---
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch
        DynamicEndPointSnitch: enabled
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
                b237cd5a-fbfd-3fdc-b3ba-d435b41372f2: [---]

Stats for all nodes:
        Live: 5
        Joining: 0
        Moving: 0
        Leaving: 0
        Unreachable: 0

Data Centers:
        ap-southeast-1 #Nodes: 5 #Down: 0

Database versions:
        4.1.2: [---]
```

And after it take some time it will back to normal (around 30 mins)
And no error logs from system.log debug.log gc.log

I would like to know how can I proceed to debug with this case, Thanks!

nodetool check, logs check, jmx metrics check.

Comment: I'd start by investigating any apps or jobs that are active during that time, and see what their access patterns look like.